# How to pay for Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I've been trying to follow the BigQuery tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/browser-tool-quickstart

I'm at the part where I create a table for the baby name data.  When I try to create the table I get:

```
Billing has not been enabled for this project
```

I would happily spend a few dollars to learn more about how this works, however, I have no idea where to plugin my credit card.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://console.developers.google.com/billing

You can enable project-wise billing.